# How to check if a character in a string is a digit or letter

Tags: java

I have the user entering a single character into the program and it is stored as a string. I would like to know how I could check to see if the character that was entered is a letter or a digit. I have an if statement, so if its a letter its prints that it's a letter, and the same for a digit. The code I have so far doesn't work but I feel like I'm close. Any help you can offer is appreciated.

```
  System.out.println("Please enter a single character: ");
  String character = in.next();

  System.out.println(character);

  if (character.isLetter()){
    System.out.println("The character entered is a letter.");
  }
  else (character.isDigit()){
    Syste.out.println("The character entered is a digit.");
```

Comment: You need `else if` not `else` for that to compile.

Comment: the else statement has two compile errors, insert assignment operator expression.

Comment: And change `Syste` to `System` ;-)

Comment: You name a String variable "character" then you call the method isLetter() which doesn't exist in the String class, but does exist in the Character class, but "character" is not a Character.  The question is very tricky.

Answer (score 76):

You could use:

```
    if (Character.isLetter(character.charAt(0))){
    ....
```

Comment: it says this method is undefined

Comment: See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29)

Comment: @Reimeus - Do variables of type `char` have a `.charAt(0)` method?

Comment: No. `character` is actually a string in the question.

Comment: the problem coming back is at String character = in.next(). It says "in cannot be resolved"

Comment: Nvm, fixed it, forgot to do Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: How would I apply this to an array?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. If you put all the details in a new question, there will be many people only too delighted to answer :)

Answer (score 27):

You could use the existing methods from the Character class. Take a look at the docs:

[http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29)

So, you could do something like this...

```
String character = in.next();
char c = character.charAt(0);
...
if (Character.isDigit(c)) { 
    ... 
} else if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
    ...
}
...
```

If you ever want to know exactly how this is implemented, you could always look at the Java source code.

Answer (score 16):

Ummm, you guys are forgetting the `Character.isLetterOrDigit` method:

```
boolean x;
String character = in.next();
char c = character.charAt(0);
if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(charAt(c)))
{ 
  x = true;
}
```

Comment: I think it's `isLetterOrDigit()`

Comment: This doesn't tell you which of the two it is. It only verifies that it is at least a number or digit. It would return true for "A" or "2".

Answer (score 7):

This is a little tricky, the value you enter at keyboard, is a String value, so you have to pitch the first character with method `line.chartAt(0)` where, 0 is the index of the first character, and store this value in a char variable as in `char c= line.charAt(0)`
now with the use of method [`isDigit()`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) and [`isLetter()`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) from class `Character` you can differentiate between a Digit and Letter.

here is a code for your program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Practice
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Input a letter"); 
   String line = in.nextLine();
   char c = line.charAt(0);
   if( Character.isDigit(c))
   System.out.println(c +" Is a digit");
   else if (Character.isLetter(c))
   System.out.println(c +" Is a Letter");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

By using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
boolean isChar = character.matches("[a-zA-z]{1}");
boolean isDigit = character.matches("\\d{1}");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
char charInt=character.charAt(0);   
if(charInt>=48 && charInt<=57){
    System.out.println("not character");
}
else
    System.out.println("Character");
```

Look for ASCII table to see how the int value are hardcoded .

Comment: @vandey.. Why would you want to re-invent the wheel?? There already pre-defined method to do this task for you..

Comment: It is just that if the OP wants to learn, he can understand what actually is going on when he calls those method.

Comment: @RohitJain, `Character.isDigit` cheks for digit in **any** digit system, and this solution will ignore anything except arabic digits

Answer (score 3):

This is the way how to check whether a given  character is alphabet or not

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char c = sc.next().charAt(0); 
    if((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
         System.out.println(c + " is an alphabet.");
    else
        System.out.println(c + " is not an alphabet.");
}
```

Comment: What if it's special symbol ?

Answer (score 2):

```
     char temp = yourString.charAt(0);
     if(Character.isDigit(temp))
     {
         ..........
     }else if (Character.isLetter(temp))
     {
          ......
      }else
     {
      ....
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;

public class String_char 
{

    public static void main(String arg[]){   

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the value");
        String data;
        data = in.next();

        int len = data.length();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
            char ch = data.charAt(i);

            if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')){
                System.out.println("Number ");
            }
            else if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')){
            System.out.println("Character");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Symbol");
             }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your string into character..

```
String character = in.next();
char myChar = character.charAt(0);

if (Character.isDigit(myChar)) {
   // print true
}
```

Check [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) for other methods..

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by Regular Expression as follows
you could use this code

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
String NumberPattern = "[0-9]+";
String Number = et.getText().toString();

if (Number.matches(NumberPattern) && s.length() > 0)
{ 
    //code for number
}
else
{
    //code for incorrect number pattern
}
```

Comment: et is of editText. + sign is for the occurances of digits from 0 to 9

Answer (score 0):

I have coded a sample program that checks if a string contains a number in it! I guess it will serve for this purpose as well.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String c;
        boolean b;

        System.out.println("Enter the value");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        c = s.next();
        b = containsNumber(c);
        try {
            if (b == true) {
                throw new CharacterFormatException();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Valid String \t" + c);
            }
        } catch (CharacterFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception Raised-Contains Number");

        }
    }

    static boolean containsNumber(String c) {
        char[] ch = new char[10];
        ch = c.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            if ((ch[i] >= 48) && (ch[i] <= 57)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`CharacterFormatException` is a user defined Exception. Suggest me if any changes can be made.